# How to get the size of the font on a webpage?

Tags: parsing, web-crawler, render

In webspiders/crawlers how can i get the actual *initial* rendered size of the font a user sees in an HTML document, *keeping CSS in mind.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rendered text size?
A user can change the text size at will using his/her browser settings.
Not to mention that different browsers render the same content slightly differently.

Comment: The browser's default size will be used, unless it's set somewhere. And usually the font is always set at least once in the CSS. The crawler should probably look at the DOM hierarchy to figure out which CSS setting is used, unless it's overwritten with inline CSS in the HTML itself. Quite a lot of work, but possible. It's probably easier though to separate headers from normal text to have a better idea of what's what.

Comment: I agree, you'd have to pretty much replicate the DOM on the server by parsing all the html/css/js to get the actual size of rendered text.  Sounds like a helluva project.

Comment: Definitely a helluva project. Worse if you want to know about IE pixel heights. Less bad if just gecko (or whatever Firefox uses these days) and webkit will suffice - then my thoughts below seem more tractable for server-side execution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are satisfied with the answer being for the 'default', no user customization view for this purpose (which seems likely), I believe you are looking at a fairly painful scenario:

- Embed a rendering engine with CSS
  support in your spider. Prefer the
  use of an engine which matches most
  of your users, or alternatively use
  all three common engines and store
  the information for all of them. The
  ease of embedding varies widely on
  your consuming technology.
- Load the URI being spidered in the
  rendering engine(s).
- Using the engine's API, query it's
  font metrics for an element
  containing what you consider
  representative text (choosing this is
  an exercise for which I won't even
  begin to predict a strategy). How you
  access this will depend entirely on
  the embedding scenario for your
  engine.

I expect this is the 'hard way', but I'm not sure there is an 'easy' way.